# 500 Internal: Multiple actions were found that match the request

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-web-api, routes

**AJAX**

```
 $.ajax({
                url: '../api/TechViews/SView',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify({ Filter: JSON.stringify(eth.Data), Type: $('.productType.active').data('name'), Name: $('#txtView').val() }),
                global: false,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                   alert('success');

                },
                error: function (xhrequest, ErrorText, thrownError) {
                   alert('Fail');
                }
            });
```

**Controller**

```
    [Route("SView")]
    [HttpPost]
    public string Post([FromBody]TechViewsModel value)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        return result;
    }

    [Route("DView")]
    [HttpPost]
    public string Post([FromBody]TechViewsModel value)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        return result;
    }
```

The namespace used for `Route` is `AttributeRouting.Web.Mvc`. On the `AJAX` call i get 2 errors as `500 (Internal Server Error)`

1. For `TechViews`
2. For `SView`

and the response is `"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Multiple actions were found that match the request: \r\nSystem.String Post`

**RouteConfig**

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "LoginPage", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

I tried ,

1. Removing `HttpPost`
2. Re-Order `HttpPost` and `Route`
3. Changing names for naming conntraints
4. Removing `FromBody` in the param
5. Changing the Method name and Parameter Type.

When i used only one post with no `Route` the same code works fine.

Where am i wrong?

Comment: Those two actions can't exist in the same controller class. C# would not allow it. They have the same name, parameters and return type.

Comment: @juunas Let me know what are the alternatives i have to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Enable  `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()` option in api routing configuration.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

In global.asax.cs

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

Comment: And install HelpPage nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage/ , will provide you api route documentation by '../api/help' and helpful to solve this kind of issues

Comment: Installed but it didn't help. Also, GlobalConfiguration does not have definition for Configure. Does it?

Comment: Check namespace used for GlobalConfiguration , it should be  System.Web.Http from System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll

Comment: Yes it is, But still i didn't get that.

Comment: Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost package installed ?

Comment: Not sure. But it comes from System.Web.Http.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139857/discussion-between-jignesh-variya-and-iamcr).